# fgets not waiting for user input

Tags: c, input, fgets

In the given code fgets is not waiting for input.

I tried using scanf but it's giving unusual error(Exception thrown at 0x0F74DDF4 (ucrtbased.dll)). I'm using **Visual Studio 2015** for debugging my code. Can anyone explain why fgets is not waiting for input?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<process.h>

//GLOBAL-VARIABLE DECLARTION
#define MAX 1000

//GLOBAL-STRUCTURES DECLARATION
struct census
{
char city[MAX];
long int p;
float l;
};

//GLOBAL-STRUCTURE-VARIABLE DECLARATION
struct census cen[] = { 0,0,0 };

//USER-DEFINED FUNCTION
void header();

void header()
{
printf("*-*-*-*-*CENSUS_INFO*-*-*-*-*");
printf("\n\n");
}

//PROGRAM STARTS HERE
main()
{   
//VARIABLE-DECLARATION
int i = 0, j = 0;
//int no_of_records = 0;

//FUNCTION CALL-OUT
header();

printf("Enter No. of City : ");
scanf_s("%d", &j);

printf("\n\n");

printf("Enter Name of City, Population and Literacy level");
printf("\n\n");

for (i = 0;i < j;i++)
{
    printf("City No. %d - Info :", i + 1);
    printf("\n\n");

    printf("City Name :");
    fgets(cen[i].city, MAX, stdin);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Population : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &cen[i].p);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Literacy : ");
    scanf_s("%f", &cen[i].l);
    printf("\n");
}

//TERMINAL-PAUSE
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: @user3121023 any way to fix that?

Comment: @Szymson scanf do not work in visual studio. We have to use scanf_s and its giving me error.

Comment: @user3121023 I would like to use fgets but is there anything else for taking integer or float input except scanf?

Comment: Try using fgets() into a separate char array, then sscanf() to parse from that.

Comment: You can't just replace `scanf` with `scanf_s`; if you have `%s`, `%c` or `%[` formats, as is likely when you want to emulate `fgets`, you must provide a max buffersize for each in `scanf_s`. But I'm with @jamieguinan: Use a two-step approach throughout for interactive input: First read a line, then read data from the line.

Comment: @jamieguinan I didn't get it - can you please edit my code and post it? (sorry I'm new in C xD)

Comment: `scanf_s("%f", &cen[i].l);` does not consume the `'\n'` that follows the number.  The next `fgets(cen[i].city, MAX, stdin);` then reads that 1 character `'\n'`.  Simply do not used `scanf()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use `fgets` followed by `sscanf`.

Declare this at the top,

```
char line[MAX];
```

Then use `fgets` to get a line, and `sscanf` to parse the int value out of it,

```
printf("Enter No. of City : ");
fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
sscanf(line, "%d", &j);
```

Similar pattern for `l`

```
printf("Literacy : ");
fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
sscanf(line, "%f", &cen[i].l);
```

Comment: Btw, if you use a value greater than 3 for `j`, you're going to overflow your `cen]\` array, but that's a separate problem.

Comment: And it would be nice to check return values like @user694733 does. My example is a simple modification to the original, which should work for sane input.

Comment: can you please tell me why it's overflowing when I use a value greater than 3 for j ?

Comment: @Eddy, when you declare `cen[]` without a size in the brackets, the compiler will size it to the number of items in the `{}`s, where you have 3 zeros. You could declare it `cen[10]` and handle up to 10, or as many as you want. For safety, you could put and `if` test before the loop and break/return/exit if `j` is bigger than your array.

Comment: I figured it out jamie but thnx for replying :)

Answer (score 3):

When you enter the number of cities and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `scanf` doesn't read the linebreak character from input. `fgets` then tries to read but finds the linebreak, and immediately stops.

Don't use `scanf` to read numbers, use `fgets` to read in string first and then `sscanf`(or [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol)/[`strtof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof)/[`strtod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtod)) to convert to number.

```
char temp[LIMIT];
if(fgets(temp, LIMIT, stdin)) {
    if(sscanf(temp, "%d", &j) == 1) {
        // Ok
    }
    else {
        // Handle sscanf error
    }
}
else {
    // Handle fgets error
}
```

Comment: thnx for the help I really appreciate it :)